# Using multiple character column delimiter in column command

Tags: bash, shell, formatting, zsh

I often use the `column` command to format some lines just by piping it into `column -t -s ','` or something, but every once in a while I want to use a multi-character separator. Is that possible with the column command, and if not, is there some other shell built-in (or not built in) that already exists and supports this? Basically I want something that can handle `column -t -s 'XYZ'` and will format this

```
Xfirstvalue XYZ secondvalue XYZ thirdvalue
1valueY XYZ 2value XYZ 3valZue
```

into

```
Xfirstvalue secondvalue thirdvalue
1valueY     2value      3valZue
```

but instead it gives

```
firstvalue    secondvalue    thirdvalue
1value                       2value       3val  ue
```

Comment: The problem is that `X`, `Y`, and `Z` are all recognized as column separators, but I want the combination of them to be the separator. Pardon my bad example, I've updated the question.

Comment: assuming ` XYZ ` only shows up as a delimiter, and you can pick a single character to use as a new delimiter (that doesn't also show up in the data), one (obvious?) idea would be a conversion of the delimiter, eg, `sed 's/ XYZ /|/g' data_file | column -t  -s '|'`

Comment: That....is somewhat obvious in retrospect. Works fine for my use case. Appreciate the help.